# Form-based File Upload in HTML and remote files

Tags: html, forms, file, input

I was reading [RFC 1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867) about Form-based File Upload in HTML section [5.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867#section-5.7) regarding Remote files with third-party transfer but instead of specifications/implementations there is a question and suggestion.

Then I have checked [RFC 2854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2854), which obsoletes RFC 1867, but there is nothing regarding remote files.

My question is there any specification on form-based file upload in HTML and remote files? Is this possible to process/attach remote files accessing them via URLs?

What I'm looking for is that instead of "choose file"->select->open file as a file input it want to grab selected remote files (from a modal) via provided URLs to them and send same one as a file input handler. Something like Google Drive allows to attach as a file not a link to it in Gmail platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML specifications aren't published as RFCs any more.

The current specification is [HTML 5.1 2nd Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

It defines [file inputs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-file-upload), but the user interface (including where files can be selected from) is an implementation detail left up to the browser.

I'm not aware of any browser that allows a file to be selected using a URL, but most will support files shared using the operating system's supported network filesystems.

It also defines [url inputs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-url) which could provide the server with a URL (leaving the actual fetching of the data from that URL up to server side code).

Comment: What I'm looking for is that instead of "choose file"->select->open file as a file input it will grab selected remote files (from a modal) via provided URLs to them and send same one as a file input handler. Something like Google Drive allows to attach as a file not a link to it.

Comment: @JackTheKnife — As I said: That's an implementation detail for the browser developers to put in if they want to and I'm not aware of any that have.

Comment: So it may be that Google simple sends a file URL to some sort of back end, which "extracts" file which later is attached as a file in Gmail? Just trying to figure out how to handle my case of "attaching" remote files.

Comment: Yes. That's the approach I described in the last paragraph of the answer.